# How often does your IP change when on a mobile network?

Tags: mobile, ip, user-identification

I have a problem where I try to identify people that are writing to me on my website; is it one guy that just wont stop writing me, or is it that 100 different people want to give me their opinion on the subject?

So I started adding the IP of the poster to the entry in the backend. I know usually the public IP wont change much if at all on Wifi, and the IP will change when someone jumps on a mobile network, but when on that mobile network, does your IP change a lot? Can I still assume different IP = probably different person?

Or does it change often, like every time the mobile tower you connect to changes, your IP changes?

So to wrap it up in a single question: During normal use of a mobile device, how often does the public IP change?